# Can we estimate the divisor function?

Tags: divisor-sum, divisor-counting-function

I have a question about the estimate of the divisor function.
Let
$$ d(n)=\sum_{d|n}1.$$

I proved that
$$\sum_{n<x}d(n) \ll x \log x \\
\sum_{n<x}\frac{d(n)}{n} \ll (\log x)^2.$$

My question is whether we can get the estimate $$d(n) \ll_{\varepsilon} n^{\varepsilon} $$ for any $\varepsilon >0$ from above two inequality.

If you have an idea, please tell me about my question.